# Split a string with certain scheme, is this a bad practice?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string that looks like this

```
[{ "title":"","comment":"","size":"18.298","name":"logo.png",
"filename":"fu_mucqjrfifpadsw8","ext":"png" }]
```

I want to get filename.ext out of it. To me it looks like I could do this easier than the following (which does work but seems bad practice -or is it?)

How I am extracting it currently:

```
$logo = explode(':',$string);
$ext = str_replace('"', "", $logo[6]);
$ext = str_replace(' }]', "", $ext);
$logo = explode(',',$logo[5]);
$logo=str_replace('"', "", $logo[0]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like JSON data.  You can use php's [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get an array then index the array.

```
$string = '[{ "title":"","comment":"","size":"18.298","name":"logo.png","filename":"fu_mucqjrfifpadsw8","ext":"png" }]';
$data = json_decode($string, true);
// Access filename field
$data[0]['filename'];
```

Answer (score 5):

This is *horrible* practice. Your data is in JSON format, so what you should do is use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to a PHP variable and then navigate to the information you need.

For example, to get the filename + extension:

```
$data = json_decode($string, true);
$filename = $data[0]['filename'];
$ext = $data[0]['ext'];

$allTogether = $filename.'.'.$ext;
```

Comment: thats why i asked. i dindt know it was json ... tried to google it but how do you google for a string structure like that :D